# How to suppress all output of diff in shell scripting?

Tags: shell, diff

Greetings,

I was wondering if there was a way to suppress ALL output of the diff command
so that it doesn't output the differences but only returns a success status?

```
diff $FILE1 $FILE2
if [ $? -ne 0 ];then
    echo Does not match output.
else
    echo Match.
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If all you want to know is whether the two files differ, `cmp` is the better tool.

```
if cmp -s file1 file2; then
   echo Files not changed.
fi
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `echo Files not changed.` ?

Comment: @Maros Hluska. Updated.

Comment: Looks like `cmp` doesn't support most of the features of `diff` e.g. ignore white-space. So not really an alternative.

Answer (score 18):

```
diff $FILE1 $FILE2 &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, diff has options that cmp has not (like -w)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the recursive feature of diff and chose:

```bash
if [[ "$(diff -rq DIR1 DIR2 | head -n1)" ]]; then
   echo "Directory Contents Differ"
else
   echo "Directory Contents Same"
fi
```

because head will hangup on diff after the first line of difference output which should cause diff to stop early (no need to test anything else).